# web application form insert data into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a relational SQL database with three tables - CompanyProfile, AnnualTurnover, MainActivity which are connected to each other by foreign keys.

CompanyProfile has:

```
PK: CompanyID int,
    CompanyName nvarchar(50),
    StateAids float,
    Subsidy float,
    TurnoverID --> FK,
    MainActivityID --> FK
```

AnnualTurnover:

```
PK: TunoverID int,
    Turnover float
```

MainActivity:

```
PK: ActivityID int,
    ActivityName nvarchar(50)
```

I have a web application form with textboxes for CompanyName,StateAids,Subsidy; dropdownlist for "ActivityName" and three radio buttons for "Turnover".

I also have a button(Add), so when the user clicks on the button, the data is stored in the database.

My problem is that I can not understand how to insert the data from the textboxes (which obviously store text) into CompanyProfile when I have two other foreign keys which are int datatype.

What is the best approach to do that?

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: The best approach is to use drop down list for the foreign key,  not a textbox.

Comment: Not sure if I understood the problem, but you should insert the values to AnnualTurnover and MainActivity, capture the ids with scope_identity() for both of them and use those ids when inserting the row into CompanyProfile

Comment: If you have to use textbox, then you have to validate the user input to make sure that it's a valid value for the foreign key, but it's not the best practice to do

Comment: Thank you, guys, I do not know how to use scope_identity(), but I will try. :) have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correct then you are trying to read 'StateAids' and 'Subsidy' field values through textbox controls. If so, then my suggestion would be that you Validate on Add button click that data entered is of float type and convert into float type before inserting into database because text property of textbox control always produces string.